# ORDER BY statement syntax error in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have just started learning SQL and I came across an ORDER BY error (Error Code 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax) when trying to order my data from the first SELECT block. The issue is resolved when I move this ORDER BY statement to the second or third block, I was just curios why this was?

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Bronze' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points < 2000
ORDER BY first_name

UNION 

SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Silver' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000

UNION

SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Gold' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points > 3000
```

Comment: When you apply ORDER BY clause to the separate subsuery of UNION query you MUST wrap this subquery (including its ORDER BY) into the parenthesis. PS. ORDER BY for separate subquery without LIMIT makes no sense - server MAY alter the ordering during UNION (and I think it will - because of UNION DISTINCT, not UNION ALL). For to apply ordering to whole output you must put ORDER BY after last subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `case`:

```
SELECT customer_id, first_name, points,
       (CASE WHEN points < 2000 then 'Bronze'
             WHEN points < 3000 then 'Silver'
             ELSE 'Gold'
        END) as type
FROM customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a `UNION` with an `ORDER BY` clause, the `ORDER BY` goes at the end of the set of `UNION`'s as follows.

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Bronze' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points < 2000

UNION 

SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Silver' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000

UNION

SELECT
    customer_id,
    first_name,
    points,
    'Gold' AS type
FROM customers
WHERE points > 3000

ORDER BY first_name
```

SQL server views the results of the `UNION` as one result set and you simply order that one result set - the result of the `UNION`.

Also, see example A in this article from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15